# Drag and drop not working with new Jquery-ui-min 1.12

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I was getting error after updating Jquery-ui-min 1.12.1
It was worked well in 1.11.4

I was getting this error
element.sortable is not a function

Comment: You should add a code sample or a JSFiddle so we can simulate your problem. Please provide more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is too vague. Please add your code and include any details you may see from your JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by downgrading to stable version.
I have downgraded to Jquery-ui-min 1.12.0 from Jquery-ui-min 1.12.1